# How to find prime numbers in entered number range

Tags: javascript, arrays, primes

I'm just trying to find prime numbers of an entered range of numbers. I have no clue how to calculate finding primes. I need to add them to an array and output the array after. I put a placeholder for the calculation... I just can't seem to figure out how find the primes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>LeapYears</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */

        function calcPrimeNumber(){

                var beginNum = document.numbers.firstNum.value;
                var endNum = document.numbers.secondNum.value;
                var primeNumbs = new Array();


                var ctr = 0;
                while (beginNum <= endNum){ //throwaway
                    if ((beginNum % beginNum == 0) && (beginNum % 1 == 0)){
                        primeNumbs[ctr] = beginNum;
                        ++ctr;
                    }

                    ++beginNum;
                }

                if (primeNumbs == 0){
                    window.alert("There were no leap years within the range.");
                }

                else {
                    outputPrimeNums(primeNumbs);
                }

        }

        function outputPrimeNums(primes){
            document.write("<h2>Prime Numbers</h2>");
            for (i=0;i<primes.length;i++){
                    document.write(primes[i] + "<br/>");
                }

        }


        /* ]]> */
        </script>


    </head>


    <body>
        <form name="numbers">

            Beginning Number: <input type="text" name="firstNum" /> End Number: <input type="text" name="secondNum" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Find Prime Numbers" onclick="calcPrimeNumber()" />

        </form>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: How would I find the prime numbers in the entered range if it doesn't start at 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this full page of prime no example

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>LeapYears</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */

        function calcPrimeNumber(){

                var beginNum = parseInt(document.numbers.firstNum.value);
                var endNum = parseInt(document.numbers.secondNum.value);
                var primeNumbs = new Array();


                var ctr = beginNum;
                while(ctr<=endNum)
                {
                    if(isPrime(ctr)==true)
                    {
                        primeNumbs[primeNumbs.length] = ctr;
                    }
                    ctr = ctr+1;

                }

                if (primeNumbs.length == 0){
                   document.getElementById('output_content').innerHTML = "There were no prime no within the range.";
                }

                else {
                    outputPrimeNums(primeNumbs);
                }

        }

        function isPrime(num)
        {
            var flag = true;
            for(var i=2; i<=Math.ceil(num/2); i++)
            {
                if((num%i)==0)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return flag;    
        }

        function outputPrimeNums(primes){
            var html = "<h2>Prime Numbers</h2>";
            for (i=0;i<primes.length;i++){
                    html += primes[i] + "<br/>";
                }
            document.getElementById('output_content').innerHTML = html;
        }


        /* ]]> */
        </script>


    </head>


    <body>
        <form name="numbers">

            Beginning Number: <input type="text" name="firstNum" /> End Number: <input type="text" name="secondNum" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Find Prime Numbers" onclick="calcPrimeNumber()" />

        </form>
        <div id="output_content">
        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some algorithm to check whether a given no is prime no or not inside while loop  . 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Efficient_Prime_Number_Generating_Algorithms

Comment: that wikibook page is bad advice, sorry. :) the code there is terrible, and terribly slow. it shows the timing of 5.6 seconds for primes under 1 mln, but [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068548/849891) has it at 0.07 seconds for fastest plane Python code. that's right, 80 times faster is a lot, even if on different computers.

Comment: That means You think that some one should write a code for this simple task .  To check whether a given no is prime or not . What is the running time of above code that You have marked as answer .

Comment: I'm not the OP, I couldn't possibly mark an answer as accepted. :) That's only for the OP to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

**You need two loops here** - the first to run between `beginNum` and `endNum` and the second to run from 1 to `beginNum` **for each value of beginNum in the outer loop**.

Try replacing the main section of your code with the following. (For clarity, I'm going to introduce a new variable - `numberBeingTested`.)

```
var ctr = 0;
var numberBeingTested = beginNum;

while (numberBeingTested <= endNum){ //throwaway

    var testDivisor = 2;
    var isPrime = true;

    while (testDivisor < numberBeingTested ){ //throwaway
        if (numberBeingTested % testDivisor == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
        }                    

    ++testDivisor;
    }

    if (isPrime){
        primeNumbs[ctr] = numberBeingTested;
        ++ctr;
    }

    ++numberBeingTested;
}
```

Note that there are many possible improvements here - for a start, this code as it stands will tell you that 1 is prime, and there are significant possible performance improvements (such as testing possible divisors up to the square root of the number being tested rather than the number itself) - but for your purposes it will probably suffice.

Comment: Thanks, you made it very clear.

Answer (score 0):

What I try was to edit [Sieve of Atkin algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) from [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12287599/2021523):

```
function getPrimes(min, max) {
    var sieve = [], i, j, primes = [];
    for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
        if (!sieve[i]) {
            // i has not been marked -- it is prime
            if (i >= min) {
                primes.push(i);
            }
            for (j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

console.log(getPrimes(10, 100));
```

This will give you array with prime numbers from `min` to `max`. It still has to go through all number from 2, so maybe there will be more effective way how to achieve this.

Comment: this is not a sieve of Atkin, but of Eratosthenes. :) the `j = i << 1` bit is a *"fast way of multiplying `i` by 2"* but it's a very slow way of starting your work from `i^2`.