# I have made a for-loop in Javascript to check if a number is a primenumber or not. But it's not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have made a for-loop in Javacript to check if a number is a primenumber or not. But it's not working. Who can help me with this?

```
Fill in a limit:<br>
<input type="number" id="limit" placeholder="limit" /></br>
<input type="submit" value="Go!" onclick="primenumbers()" /><br><br>
<p id="answer">Here comes the answer</p>

<script>
var answer = document.getElementById('answer');

function primenumbers() {
    var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;

    answer.innerHTML = ' ';
    for(var i=0; i<=limit; i++) {
        if(i == 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113){
            answer.innerHTML += i+' = '+'Primenumber'+'<br>';
        } else {
            answer.innerHTML += i+' = '+'Not a primenumber'+'<br>';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: For future reference, this may help you check for primality:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12287599/1387572. It uses a for loop!

Answer (score 2):

`if(i == 2, 3, 5, ... , 113)` is just a really long way of writing `if (113)`, which is always true. That is how the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works.

If you want to test if a value is included in a set of values you can use an array for the set, and search for that value in the set using [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if ([2, 3, 5, ..., 113].indexOf(i) >= 0)
```

If you want that to work in Internet Explorer versions 8 or below you need to implement `Array.prototype.indexOf` in Javascript. There is a [Polyfill here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill).

Comment: i dont thinks so. The right part returns the last value 113.

Comment: @ele The comma operator evaluates its left expression and then its right expression and evaluates to the value of its right expression. For example: `var x = (5, 7, 50);` will assign 50 to `x` and then doing `var y = (x++, x++, 300)` will make `x == 52` and `y == 300`.

Comment: you are right. Pls add that he shouldnt "calculate" Prime numbers like that. I voted your answer up.

Comment: @ele I agree, that is not how primality testing is generally done, but I suspect that it suits his needs, as he must be aware that it breaks for primes `> 113`, and I think getting into the details of how to test for primes may be out of the scope of his question.

Comment: @YTowOnt9 I have tried a lot, but I don't understand how to use 'indexOf'. Can you help me a little bit?