# Or Boolean Expression within the If Statement within a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

When I check the number to see if it is prime via the Or Boolean statement, it does not complete the check, and it returns the entire array.

```
function sumPrimes(num) {
  var arr = [];

  var prime;
  for(var i = 1; i <=num; i++){
   if(i%2 !== 0 || i%3 !== 0 || i%5 !== 0){
     arr.push(i);
   }
  }
  return arr;
}

sumPrimes(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic you want is either

```
if (i%2 !== 0 && i%3 !== 0 && i%5 !== 0) // not divisible by 2 and not divisible by 3
                                         // and not divisible by 5
```

or

```
if (!(i%2 === 0 || i%3 === 0 || i%5 === 0)) // not divisible by 2 or 3 or 5
```

And of course you need to consider that this only works for primes up to 48.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you just get a ["get prime numbers algorithm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966520/how-to-find-prime-numbers-between-0-100) like this:

```
function getPrimes(max) {
  var sieve = [], i, j, primes = [];
  for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
      if (!sieve[i]) {
          // i has not been marked -- it is prime
          primes.push(i);
          for (j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) {
              sieve[j] = true;
          }
      }
  }
  return primes;
}
```

And sum that up using reduce

```
var sumPrimes = function(num) {
  var primes = getPrimes(num)
  var sum = primes.reduce(function(sum, prime) {
    return sum + prime
  }, 0)
}
```