# how to do descending order prime numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, numbers

There's a way I can "invert" my array of prime numbers? or I have to do in other logic way.

There's my code

```
var primos = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    var fake = false;
    for (var j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
        if (i%j==0 && j!=i) {
            fake = true;
        }
    }
    if (fake === false) {
        primos.push(i);
    }
}
for(i = primos.length; i > 0; i--) {
    console.log(primos[i]);
}
```

[image]

I want the result to be the array but in descending order
Like `[97, 89, 83, ...]`

Comment: you want to reverse the array? you can also `unshift` which adds values to the head of the array ...

Comment: Do you want to reverse the array or have your algorithm outputting the array on order crescent?

Comment: You can refer to this if its the second option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966520/how-to-find-prime-numbers-between-0-100

Comment: unshift doesent solve it :(, i will specify more my problem

Comment: yeah, have to say, not sure what `decrescent` even means, it's not an English word at all ... how about you specify what your result should be

Comment: @JaromandaX i guess it is https://i.imgur.com/G550TR4.png

Comment: so, unshift **WILL** produce the right result - if it doesn't then the code isn't producing the primes correctly at all

Comment: wow, it is too - my browsers spell checker doesn't think so :p

Comment: yep @JaromandaX unshift solve it :)! I get it now, I was trying to use directly in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply revert the result you can use the Array prototype method reverse:

```
var primos = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    var fake = false;
    for (var j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
        if (i%j==0 && j!=i) {
            fake = true;
        }
    }
    if (fake === false) {
        primos.push(i);
    }
}
primos = primos.reverse();
for(i = primos.length; i > 0; i--) {
    console.log(primos[i]);
}
```

Take a look at this other answer for some ideas on other ways to accomplish this:

[How to find prime numbers between 0 - 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966520/how-to-find-prime-numbers-between-0-100?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: use unshift instead of push, no more reverse required :p

Comment: or loop i from 100...2 :p